# Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 WLAN does not work on installed Arch

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, linux-kernel, broadcom

I have a Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 WLAN Controller in my netbook. When I boot the Arch live ISO and set up the network with wpa_supplicant everything works fine.
On the installed Arch I get the following Error:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlp2s0 -D wext -c ../wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B

brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_config: change power-safe mode: false (implement)
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
```

I can't figure out why it's not working as the brcmscmac driver is part of the kernel and works flawlessly on the live ISO.

```
Output of lspci:
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)

Output of ip link show:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
link/ether 04:7d:7b:22:72:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT qlen 1000
link/ether 7c:e9:d3:20:3d:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Trying to setup wlp2s0 gives the same error:

```
ip link set up wlp2s0

brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_config: change power-safe mode: false (implement)
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
```

The module should be loaded (brcmsmac for the pci card):

```
Output of lsmod | grep "brcmscmac\|bcma\|b43":
brcmsmac              485657  0 
cordic                   844  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil                3721  1 brcmsmac
b43                   341637  0 
mac80211              389700  2 b43,brcmsmac
cfg80211              336964  3 b43,brcmsmac,mac80211
ssb                    48159  1 b43
pcmcia                 40213  2 b43,ssb
bcma                   30352  3 b43,brcmsmac
mmc_core               86479  3 b43,ssb,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
```

Thanks in advance for all suggestions.

Comment: Are [both the required modules](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#brcmsmac.2Fbrcmfmac) loading?

Comment: I added the output of lsmod to the problem description

Comment: Try blacklisting b43; it may be conflicting.

Comment: Tried it, same problem. Any other idea?

Comment: used broadcom-wl instead. worked like a charm

Comment: @GerdMüller. Posta as reply, and mark it as answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/broadcom_wireless), you must blacklist `b43` module because it conflicts with `brcmsmac`.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning @jasonwryan (who mentioned exactly this solution in-comments a while ago).